# Overriding prototype method and calling the original method

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to overrid the drawImage function of Html5 Canvas.Here is code.

```
var p = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawImage;
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawImage = function() {
    var len = arguments.length;
    var ig, sx, sy, swidth, sheight, x, y, width, height
    if (len === 3) {
        p(arguments[0], arguments[1] * 2, arguments[2] * 2, this);
    } else if (len === 5) {
        //Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation.
        p(arguments[0], arguments[1] * 2, arguments[2] * 2, arguments[3] * 2, arguments[4] * 2, this); 
    } else if (len === 9) {
        p(arguments[0], arguments[1] * 2, arguments[2] * 2, arguments[3] * 2, arguments[4] * 2, arguments[5] * 2, arguments[6] * 2, arguments[7] * 2, arguments[8] * 2, this);
    }
}
```

And call the function as the following.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

But It throw an error in the annotations line.
After overrided prototype method,how to call the original method.

Comment: use p.call(this, ...) instead of a simple named invocation.

Comment: It seems your are just scaling by a factor 2. Using context.scale(2,2); is a much better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to say `p.call` or `p.apply` to execute it in the correct context.

```
if (len === 3) {
    p.call(this, arguments[0], arguments[1] * 2, arguments[2] * 2);
} else if (len === 5) {
    p.call(this, arguments[0], arguments[1] * 2, arguments[2] * 2, arguments[3] * 2, arguments[4] * 2); 
} else if (len === 9) {
    p.call(this, arguments[0], arguments[1] * 2, arguments[2] * 2, arguments[3] * 2, arguments[4] * 2, arguments[5] * 2, arguments[6] * 2, arguments[7] * 2, arguments[8] * 2);
}
```

**Edit:** Here's why. When you call a javascript function, by default, it executes in the context of `window`. That means that the keyword `this` refers to window (which it shouldn't; when you call `drawImage`, `this` should refer to the canvas element). By overriding the default context, `window`, you change it to the proper context.

Example:

```
var w = document.write;
// Error
w("Test");
// Works
w.call(document, "Test");
```

Comment: He's modifying the arguments (i.e. multiplying the second argument by two etc.)

Comment: You're correct @soktinpk, my bad. There's still a much less verbose way using a simple loop and `apply` than listing all arguments individually.